# check if numpy array is subset of another array

Tags: python, numpy, set

Similar questions have already been asked on SO, but they have more specific constraints and their answers don't apply to my question.

Generally speaking, what is the most pythonic way to determine if an arbitrary numpy array is a subset of another array?  More specifically, I have a roughly 20000x3 array and I need to know the indices of the 1x3 elements that are entirely contained within a set.  More generally, is there a more pythonic way of writing the following:

```
master = [12, 155, 179, 234, 670, 981, 1054, 1209, 1526, 1667, 1853]  # some indices of interest
triangles = np.random.randint(2000, size=(20000, 3))  # some data

for i, x in enumerate(triangles):
    if x[0] in master and x[1] in master and x[2] in master:
        print i
```

For my use case, I can safely assume that len(master) << 20000. (Consequently, it is also safe to assume that master is sorted because this is cheap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily via iterating over an array in list comprehension. A toy example is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(30).reshape(10,3)
searchKey = [4,5,8]
x[[0,3,7],:] = searchKey
x
```

gives

```
 array([[ 4,  5,  8],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 4,  5,  8],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [ 4,  5,  8],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]])
```

Now iterate over the elements:

```
ismember = [row==searchKey for row in x.tolist()]
```

The result is

```
[True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False]
```

You can modify it for being a subset as in your question:

```
searchKey = [2,4,10,5,8,9]  # Add more elements for testing
setSearchKey = set(searchKey)
ismember = [setSearchKey.issuperset(row) for row in x.tolist()]
```

If you need the indices, then use

```
np.where(ismember)[0]
```

It gives

```
array([0, 3, 7])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer -- your list comprehension is more pythonic than my for loop -- but your answer does not account for the subset part of the problem. `row in searchKey` does not return whether row is a subset of searchKey.  In this example, it will always return an array of False.

Comment: I've updated the answer for your problem. The updated version considers sets.

Comment: The idea overall is good, but you should strip down the list comprehension. Something like `set_searchKey = set(searchKey); [set_searchKey.issuperset(row) for row in x]`, that way you're not converting searchkey to a set on every iteration. Also notice that x does not need to be converted to a list.

Comment: @BiRico I've modified accordingly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's quite strange, you should be able to iterate over a numpy array just like any other container. What version of python/numpy are you using.

Comment: `np.version.full_version` gives `1.6.1`. The iteration is done on all elements not on rows.

Comment: By the way: @Bi Rico, the simple change you suggested to not reproduce the set on each iteration results in a 100% speed increase when dealing with the real dataset of 20484 elements.

Comment: Nice solution. If I'm interested in finding only the *first* row that returns `True`, is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two approaches you could try:

1, Use sets. Sets are implemented much like python dictionaries and have have constant time lookups. That would look much like the code you already have, just create a set from master:

```
master = [12,155,179,234,670,981,1054,1209,1526,1667,1853]
master_set = set(master)
triangles = np.random.randint(2000,size=(20000,3)) #some data
for i, x in enumerate(triangles):
  if master_set.issuperset(x):
    print i
```

2, Use search sorted. This is nice because it doesn't require you to use hashable types and uses numpy builtins. `searchsorted` is log(N) in the size of master and O(N) in the size of triangels so it should also be pretty fast, maybe faster depending on the size of your arrays and such.

```
master = [12,155,179,234,670,981,1054,1209,1526,1667,1853]
master = np.asarray(master)
triangles = np.random.randint(2000,size=(20000,3)) #some data
idx = master.searchsorted(triangles)
idx.clip(max=len(master) - 1, out=idx)
print np.where(np.all(triangles == master[idx], axis=1))
```

This second case assumes master is sorted, as `searchsorted` implies.

Comment: searchsorted doesn't help in this case, because searchsorted virtually inserts elements into the list in their proper position, whether or not they are actually in `master`.  That is to say, the spurious entry [11,154,178] would return the same thing as the entry of interest [12,155,179].  Your code in fact doesn't even get that far, it crashes because insertions between 1853 and 2000 exceed the size of `master`.

Comment: The last line takes care of the virtually insertions, but you're right you need to clip to take care of the size issue. I've added a line to clip.

Answer (score 4):

One can also use `np.isin` which might be more efficient than the list comprehension in [@petrichor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548813/1534017). Using the same set up:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(30).reshape(10, 3)
searchKey = [4, 5, 8]
x[[0, 3, 7], :] = searchKey
array([[ 4,  5,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 4,  5,  8],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [ 4,  5,  8],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29]])
```

Now one can use `np.isin`; by default, it will work element wise:

```
np.isin(x, searchKey)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

We now have to filter the rows where all entries evaluate to `True` for which we could use `all`:

```
np.isin(x, searchKey).all(1)
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False])
```

If one now wants the corresponding indices, one can use `np.where`:

```
np.where(np.isin(x, searchKey).all(1))
(array([0, 3, 7]),)
```

EDIT:

Just realize that one has to be careful though. For example, if I do

```
x[4, :] = [8, 4, 5]
```

so, in the assignment I use the same values as in `searchKey` but in a different order, I will still get it returned when doing

```
np.where(np.isin(x, searchKey).all(1))
```

which prints

```
(array([0, 3, 4, 7]),)
```

That can be undesired.

Answer (score 2):

A more natural (and possibly faster) solution for set operations in numpy is to use the functions in `numpy.lib.arraysetops`. These generally allow you to avoid having to convert back and forth between Python's `set` type. To check if one array is a subset of another, use `numpy.setdiff1d()` and test if the returned array has 0 length:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.array([1, 5, 9])
c = np.array([-5, 5, 9])
# is `a` a subset of `b`?
len(np.setdiff1d(a, b)) == 0 # gives False
# is `b` a subset of `a`?
len(np.setdiff1d(b, a)) == 0 # gives True
# is `c` a subset of `a`?
len(np.setdiff1d(c, a)) == 0 # gives False
```

You can also optionally set `assume_unique=True` for a potential speed boost.

I'm actually a bit surprised that `numpy` doesn't have something like a built-in `issubset()` function to do the above (analogous to `set.issubset()`).

Another option is to use `numpy.in1d()` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262010/2020363)

Edit: I just realized that at some point in the distant past this bothered me enough that I wrote my own simple function:

```py
def issubset(a, b):
    """Return whether sequence `a` is a subset of sequence `b`"""
    return len(np.setdiff1d(a, b)) == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

starting with:

> `master=[12,155,179,234,670,981,1054,1209,1526,1667,1853]  #some indices of interest`
>
> `triangles=np.random.randint(2000,size=(20000,3)) #some data`

What's the most pythonic way to find indices of triplets contained in master? try using `np.in1d` with a list comprehension:

```
inds = [j for j in range(len(triangles)) if all(np.in1d(triangles[j], master))]
```

`%timeit` says ~0.5 s = half a second

--> MUCH faster way (factor of 1000!) that avoids python's slow looping? Try using `np.isin` with `np.sum` to get a boolean mask for `np.arange`:

```
inds = np.where(
 np.sum(np.isin(triangles, master), axis=-1) == triangles.shape[-1])
```

`%timeit` says ~0.0005 s = half a millisecond!

Advice: avoid looping over lists whenever possible, because for the same price as a single iteration of a python loop containing one arithmetic operation, you can call a numpy function that does thousands of that same arithmetic operation

#### Conclusion

It seems that `np.isin(arr1=triangles, arr2=master)` is the function you were looking for, which gives a boolean mask of the same shape as arr1 telling whether each element of arr1 is also an element of arr2; from here, requiring that the sum of a mask row is 3 (i.e., the full length of a row in triangles) gives a 1d mask for the desired rows (or indices, using `np.arange`) of triangles.